# ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary ignores LD_LIBRARY_PATH env variable

Tags: c++, python-3.x, macos, dll, dylib

I have a C++ dynamic library which use another set of dynamic library(VLC lib),
when I then  try to load the library(libmylib.dylib) in python with:

```
import ctypes
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libmylib.dylib')
```

I get an error like:

```
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libmylib.dylib')
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 443, in LoadLibrary
    return self._dlltype(name)
  File "/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 365, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: dlopen(./libmylib.dylib, 0x0006): Library not loaded: @rpath/libvlc.dylib
  Referenced from: ./libmylib.dylib
  Reason: tried: '/usr/local/lib/libvlc.dylib' (no such file), '/usr/lib/libvlc.dylib' (no such file)
```

In order to make it work, I have to explicitly load the VLC dependency libraries:

```
import ctypes
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlccore.dylib')
ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/libvlc.dylib')
lib = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('./libmylib.dylib')
```

I have tried to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and `LIBRARY_PATH` environment variables with no luck:

```
VLC_PLUGIN_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/plugins
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/
RUN_LD_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/
LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib/
```

Is there a way to pass the location(directory) where the VLC dynamic libraries are located and avoid to load them explicitly with `ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary` ?
How?

Note: the OS I'm using for this experiment is macOS Monterey 12.4, while the version of python I'm using is: 3.8.9

**Update**

Output of:

```
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib python3 -c 'import os; print(os.environ.get("DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH"))'
None
```

it is none, all DYLD_* libraries are completely ignored, seems to be related to [this issue](https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/84379).

Comment: Have you tried `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=...`

Comment: @Philippe yes, still not found ...

Comment: Can you try to copy `libvlc.dylib` and `libvlccore.dylib` into /usr/local/lib to see if it works ?

Comment: @Philippe Well that works for sure, but I possibly don't want to do that...

Comment: Can you try `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/lib python3.8.9 test.py` ?

Comment: @Philippe tried but doesn't work, python doesn't get the path from those env variables ...